# Проблема с работой transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Прошу помочь в аминировании динамически создаваемых объектов. Объекты создаются, но свойство `transition` не применяется как нужно. Вернее оно применяется правильно, только если я пользуюсь профайлером — тогда происходит движение, если же без него — то позиция меняется, но без анимации - просто перескакивает.

```
 .wrp {
   position: absolute;
   width: 500px;
   height: 300px;
   perspective: 500px;
   left: 200px;
 }

 .D {
   position: absolute;
   left: 100px;
   top: 100px;
 }
</style>
<script>
 function Temp() {
   $("<div class='D'>text</div>").appendTo(".wrp");
   $(".D").css({"transition": "all 2s", "transform": "translate(200px, 200px"});
 }
</script>
```

Идея: создать объект в нужной позиции (100, 100) и плавно его передвинуть в позицию (200, 200).

Comment: А можете сделать ваш код запускаемым?

Comment: У вас вот тут `"transform": "translate(200px, 200px"` опечатка.

Comment: А почему вы не можете добавить `transition` в css?

Answer (score 0):

`transition` не работает для `display: none;` и блоков, который не были в потоке при загрузки документа. В данном случае нужно использовать `animate`. За вас делать задачу не буду, однако ниже приведу пример, который вы сможете использовать для своего проекта:

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
}

@keyframes bounceInRight {
0%, to {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
}
0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
to {
    transform: translate3d(200px, 200px, 0);
}
}

.bounceInRight {
animation-name: bounceInRight;
animation-duration: .2s;
animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="block bounceInRight">
    Какой-то важный контент.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если так не получилось, то попробуй создать объект, и как только он создастся, вставить ему класс посредством того же js. 
А в css задать все необходимые свойства для этого класса, в том числе и анимацию (`transition` рекомендуется для таких легких идейных задач). Как только он будет вставлен, анимация запустится.

Вставлять css-ствойства через javascript - последняя задача для анимации. Проблем больше найдешь, чем решишь.